# How to Display an Outlook ribbon on both Explorer and Mail.Read?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am wondering if there is any easier way of using one ribbon and displaying it on both :

```
this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer";  
this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read";
```

Normally one can only set the RibbonType property once per ribbon.

This will mean that to archive this, I could just go about duplicating the "Ribbon" class with just the `RibbonType` property difference. Is there any other way of accomplishing this feat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RibbonType` is a comma delimited list, you should be able to do the following:

```
this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer, Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read";
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase.ribbontype.aspx)